# Kotlin Lambda with receiver accepts random function

Tags: kotlin

Hi I am having a kotlin function

```kotlin
fun extension(name: String, init: LambdaReceiver.() -> Unit) {
    val lambdaReceiver = LambdaReceiver(name)
    lambdaReceiver.init()
}
```

where the second parameter accepts a lambda with receiver `init: LambdaReceiver.() -> Unit`, and the structure of LambdaReceiver looks like

```kotlin
class LambdaReceiver(private val name: String) {
    private var test: Int? = null
    fun setTest(int: Int) {
        test = int
        println("$name $test")
    }
}
```

To consume the above function `extension`, I am having the below code:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    extension("testFunc") {
        setTest(1)
    }
}
```

So far good, but when I modify the consumer like below

```kotlin
fun main() {
    fun someOtherRandomFunction() {
        println("someOtherRandomFunction")
    }
    extension("testFunction") {
        someOtherRandomFunction()
        setTest(1)
    }
}
```

It was a surprise for me because there is no compilation error. I was expecting the complier to show some error because `someOtherRandomFunction` does not belongs to `LambdaReceiver`, whereas the extension's function second parameter is declared to accepts some function from `LambdaReceiver`.

Can someone shed light here, how I can restrict the `extension` function from receiving only function related to `LambdaReceiver`

Comment: Why would you want to restrict people from only using methods in `LambdaReceiver`? If, for example, computing the value that needs to be passed to `setTest` is rather complicated, people should be allowed to declare their own function to compute that. Right?

Comment: @Sweeper that makes sense, but my understand was `init: LambdaReceiver.() -> Unit`  would allow only functions from  `LambdaReceiver` not from every where.

Comment: This is similar as having `MyClass` with `foo()` function. Inside it you are not restricted to members of `MyClass` only - you can use any global functions and other classes freely.

Comment: That's not what it means. `LambdaReceiver.() -> Unit` is basically `(LambdaReceiver) -> Unit`, except the parameter is called `this`. There are other minor differences, but in no way does it "allow only functions from `LambdaReceiver`".

Comment: @Sweeper so the consumer should make sure the right function is passed?

Comment: Yes, the consumer has to provide a function that receives `LambdaReceiver`. Due to type inference in Kotlin, if we simply create a lambda without specifying types, it will automatically create a lambda that accepts `LambdaReceiver`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [overload resolution](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#overload-resolution) section of the spec for how function calls are resolved.

For a function call that is a simple name (i.e. without an explicit receiver) like `setTest(1)` or `someOtherRandomFunction()` here, the following are considered (in order):

> - Local non-extension callables named `f` in the current scope and its upwards-linked scopes, ordered by the size of the scope (smallest
>   first), excluding the package scope;
> - The overload candidate sets for each pair of implicit receivers `e` and `d` available in the current scope, calculated as if `e` is the
>   explicit receiver, in order of the receiver priority;
> - Top-level non-extension functions named `f`, in the order of:
>
>   - Callables explicitly imported into the current file;
>   - Callables declared in the same package;
>   - Callables star-imported into the current file;
>   - Implicitly imported callables (either from the Kotlin standard library or platform-specific ones).

`someOtherRandomFunction()` is the name of a local non-extension callable, so the call is resolved to that.

`LambdaReceiver.() -> Unit` doesn't restrict the functions you can use to those declared in `LambdaReceiver`. It is basically `(LambdaReceiver) -> Unit` - a function that takes a `LambdaReceiver` parameter and returns `Unit` - except that the "parameter" is called `this`, the *receiver* of the function. This allows callers of `extension` to call methods declared on `LambdaReceiver`, without an explicit receiver.

```
// if "extension" takes a (LambdaReceiver) -> Unit instead...
extension("testFunc") { foo ->
    foo.setTest(1)
    // you need to add "foo." as the receiver
}
```

If `LambdaReceiver.() -> Unit` prevented all calls to functions that are not declared in `LambdaReceiver`, it would be very inconvenient. You couldn't even use things like `listOf`!

```
someClassThatHasAList.apply { // apply takes a T.() -> Unit
    // would you really want this to not compile?
    someList = listOf(1,2,3)
}
```

---

Also note that because of this order above, you can even hide `LambdaReceiver.setTest` like this:

```
fun main() {
    fun setTest(int: Int) {}

    extension("testFunc") {
        setTest(1) // this calls the setTest declared above!
        // to call LambdaReceiver.setTest, you'd need an explicit receiver
        this.setTest(1)
    }
}
```

because local non-extension callables are looked up first.

Comment: Thanks, this explains every query that I had.